# How can I view my dead laptop on my PC?

Tags: windows-7, video

I have a laptop with a dead screen - the rest of the hardware works, I've tested it using my TV. I can plug it into my  PC via S-Video. I'm on Windows 7. Is there some program I can use to view the output of the laptop's screen? I'm trying to set it up as an Ubuntu server and need to view the output for a while. Thanks!

Comment: What make/model of laptop is it? Most PC laptops come with a VGA port allowing you to easily connect an external display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it by using a netinstall and expert. If you install it like that, you get a serial port access and also SSH access through network. Both are enough/perfect for the install. After that, once again, you'll get SSH for work.

(But if you plug an external display , the laptop should switch to it as soon as it boots. So that way you can install it. Also, try checking BIOS setup if it switches back after Bios POST.)

(Katie + Ubuntu server... Oo? >.>)

Comment: I broke rule #1 of the internet, my bad. I'll try messing around with that stuff, thanks.

Comment: =D I didn't mean it as offense sorry. :)